# Cypress console log assert `calledWith` is too strict - how to assert loose equality check?

Tags: jestjs, mocha.js, chai

I have a Cypress test that spies on the console log and expect it to be called with an object containing an array in 1 of its property and the test works but it's really strict and has to be exactly the same sort order but in some cases the order might vary and then my test fail even though the array members are what I want.

Cypress test

```js
describe('My Test', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    // create a console.log spy for later use
    cy.window().then((win) => {
      cy.spy(win.console, "log");
    });
  });

it(`should expect console log to be called with an array in 1 of its member`, () => {
      cy.get('.my-grid')
        .find('.first-page')
        .click()
        .wait(10);

      cy.window().then((win) => {
        expect(win.console.log).to.be.calledWith("Grid State changed:: ", { newValues: { dataContextIds: [12, 13, 522, 1, 3] }, type: 'rowSelection' });
      });
    });
});
```

The problem as you can imagine is with the `dataContextIds: [12, 13, 522, 1, 3]`, I would rather type in my code `[1, 3, 12, 13, 522]` without caring about the order but that fails in Cypress since it seems to be doing a strict assertion check.

I found this Chai [issue](https://github.com/chaijs/chai/issues/644) but I'm not sure how to implement that in Cypress.

If I was to write this in Jest, I think it could be written in this way (didn't test it though, refered to this Jest [article](https://codewithhugo.com/jest-array-object-match-contain/))

```js
const unorderedArray = [12, 13, 522, 1, 3];
console.log("Grid State changed:: ", { newValues: { dataContextIds: unorderedArray }, type: 'rowSelection' });

expect(myArray).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
  "Grid State changed:: ", {
    newValues: expect.objectContaining({
      dataContextIds: expect.arrayContaining([1, 3, 12, 13, 522])
    })
  }
);
```

How can I do that in Cypress?
I don't care about the array order, I care about its content only.
I don't want a strict equal, I want a loosely equal check.

Comment: This might partially help you: `expect([1, 2, 3]).to.include.members([3, 2])` from https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/assertions.html#BDD-Assertions

Comment: Interesting, is it possible to use that in an object property? If so please post and answer, which is what I'm looking for since I'm trying to use with an object `{ newValues: { dataContextIds: [12, 13, 522, 1, 3] }}` in this case it's the `dataContextIds` that could be an unordered array.

Comment: Updated the section of "How I would write in Jest" to compare against Cypress, I'm not sure if it's feasible with Cypress/Chai but that is mainly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This is a slightly different way of getting the window, but your way should work too.

```js
describe('My Test', () => {
  let called;
  Cypress.on('window:before:load', win => {

    // Stub instead of spying to make inspecting the calls easier:
    cy.stub(win.console, 'log', msg => {
      if (msg.newValues) {
        called = true;
        expect(msg.newValues.dataContextIds).to.include.members([1, 3, 12, 13, 522]);
      }
    });
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    // Reset calls to console log before each test
    called = false;
  });


  it('test', () => {
    // cy.get('.my-grid') ...

    // Make sure that at least one message had the newValues property
    // (using npm package cypress-wait-until):
    cy.waitUntil(() => called, {
      // This optional object example is taken from the docs (linked below)
      errorMsg: 'This is a custom error message',
      timeout: 2000, // waits up to 2000 ms, default to 5000
      interval: 500 // performs the check every 500 ms, default to 200
    })
  });
});
```

The package used can be found at https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-wait-until

Comment: interesting approach, I'll have to test that out, the last line though won't work in my case because I have multiple tests with multiple console call checks.

Comment: You could store all the calls, clearing them after every test, and test on that instead. I'll update my answer

Comment: Please note that I didn't have to test yet (will do today) but I have to say that I really don't like that `cy.wait` because I have a bunch of console checks and that will slow down my tests, so isn't there a way to just check that call after the console is called? It seems that it's not doable with `calledWith` but that is still the best way of waiting for the call... perhaps it might work without the wait, Cypress does a few retries but it might be flaky test though (might fail in some occasions), or maybe it won't work since the `calls.find` is done only once, we would need a way to retry

Comment: You could switch to the original way I was doing it, then assert that the number of console log calls was as expected. I agree that the wait is not good.

Comment: If I think of a better solution I'll let you know!

Comment: The problem is knowing when all the console log calls have been completed in a nice way.

Comment: If you're willing to use a library, you might be able to wait on an expression with https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-wait-until: `cy.waitUntil(() => ...);`

Comment: I heard about the `waitUntil` but didn't install it. If I have say 20 console in total, can we wait until we have 20 calls made? But even then, I don't want to do this check only at the end, I want to do it in every test, perhaps wait for a specific calls length in each test (test 1, wait until `calls.length = 1`, test 2, wait until `calls.length = 2`, ...) not sure if that is the best approach. It seems like a lot of code to overcome a simple strict vs loose equality check.

Comment: `called` is declared in the `describe` scope so the `waitUntil` code could be put into an `afterEach` to be run for every test.

Comment: This is the best approach I've been able to find. Feel free to self-answer your question if you find a better way :)

Comment: I'll award the 50 points since you're the only one who posted something ;)  maybe someday we'll get a better way of doing it